# Как перезаписать информацию в БД

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO testdb (names, leader_name, leader_discord_id, leader_vk) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    s1 = (names[i], leaders_name[i], leader_discord_id[i], leader_vk[i])
    curs.execute(sqlFormula, s1)
```

Как перезаписать информацию в таблицу, а не вставлять новую.

Comment: INSERT всегда вставляет. Изменяет существующую запись UPDATE.

Comment: Делаю update
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(names, leader_name, leader_discord_id, leader_vk) VALUES ('Night Wolfs', '',...' at line 1
  File "C:\bot\test.py", line 27, in <module>
   curs.execute(sqlFormula, s1)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(names, leader_name, leader_discord_id, leader_vk) VALUES ('Night Wolf

Comment: А не надо придумывать для сервера новый синтаксис - у него свой уже есть. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/

Comment: sqlFormula = "UPDATE testdb (names, leader_name, leader_discord_id, leader_vk) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"?

Comment: @KaigakuKibutsuji https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp. Должно быть что-то вроде `update table set col = new_value where ...` (примерно то же и в mariadb, насколько я вижу по ссылке от Akina). Нельзя просто взять и заменить просто слово insert на update, и думать что все заработает - синтаксис insert и update значительно отличается.

Comment: Вообще, такое впечатление что вам просто нужно удалять старые данные и добавлять новые, а не обновлять старые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать UPDATE, а не INSERT.
Вот синтаксис:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Твой код:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    sqlFormula = "UPDATE testdb SET names=%s, leader_name=%s, leader_discord_id=%s, leader_vk=%s"
    s1 = (names[i], leaders_name[i], leader_discord_id[i], leader_vk[i])
    curs.execute(sqlFormula, s1)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/T9vsBVu

Comment: update без where заменяет данные во всех строках, в итоге после цикла во всех строках таблицы будет последнее значение из names. Думаю это "не совсем" то, что нужно было автору вопроса.

Comment: @KaigakuKibutsuji если ответ вам не подошел (как я понимаю), не нужно отмечать его принятым.

Comment: В фрагменте запроса автора и в вопрсе не было речи об условии. Поэтому я и не добавил его.